# how to extract with Java lang on Eclipse

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass, javahelp

I think I have understood what a subclass and a superclass are, but I am having issues with creating them inside a Java file: do I have to create e new project for every class? Let's say I have two projects "A" and "B", where B is going to be the extension of A, what do I select when creating a new class on Eclipse to make folder A my superclass?
I would be ever so grateful if you could help me!! Thank you!!

Comment: You are mixing up a lot of terminology in your question talking about "projects" and "folders" and mixing them up with Java classes.  You can't make "folder A my superclass" for example because folders cannot be superclasses. A superclass has to be a class as the name suggests. I'd recommend taking a step back and reading a good tutorial about what Java classes are and how inheritance in them works. eG: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: No need for two projects. To make it simple  have one project, create a package (folder) under src and create both classes in that folder.